# Call Functions in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Using CakePHP3, I have a dynamic set of customer supplied math functions in the file Operations.php (no class since it's a generic customer supplied for many php aps) and have it saved at src/Utils/.  At the heading of my controller under the line "use App/Controller/AppController;" I have the line "use App/Utils/Operations;".  When I try to call a function it errors with undefined function.  How do I call these functions from a controller?

Comment: Do you have `namespace App\Utils\Operations;` at the very top of Operations.php?

Comment: I added it and it didn't help.

Comment: Have you updated your composer.json and run related tasks so that the PSR4 loading knows where to find your file? You haven't given us much detail about what you have done and what you have tried to make it work, so we're pretty much shooting in the dark; this may be why nobody else has commented yet. If you can add more detail to your question, you may get more help.